# Drag'n'Drop local file to browser window via Command Line for uploading

Tags: linux, macos, command-line-interface

Not quite sure if it possible at all, so decided to ask here.

I need to automate some things and search the way to drag'n'drop local file to browser window (with specific URL) via Terminal command for uploading.

I use Mac, but I think Linux will fit here as well.

If there is any solution or module on Bash / Python / Node.js I will gladly give it a try.

Comment: Duplicate of / see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137905/can-i-drag-a-file-into-a-window-without-a-file-manager

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package in python language.

you can make a POST request and send information you want to the web server.